# Best way to replace comma with dots in input text to all my project

Tags: javascript

I can't find a good solution for my problem.
I'm working using ITALIAN standard, so... numbers like `1,234,000.00` in Italian is `1.234.000,00` (so...when typing inside input text: `1234000,00`)

People, when typing inside input text box, always use comma to represent decimal, so I need a fast way to replace comma with dots during typing to facilitate my math operation in JavaScript when I need it. (using universal dot separator!)
I don't want to use `<input type="NUMBER"`, I need to use `<input type="TEXT">` to prevent conflicts with others javascript plugins I already have.

Is there a good plugin to manage this? Probably I can use a standard function like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on("change", function(e) {
    var newval = $(this).replace(",","."); 
    $(this).val(newval);
  });   
});
```

but I have to be sure this function IS ALWAYS the first executed before other `onchange` functions using the same element.

Comment: `replace(/,/g,"."); `

Comment: Why don't you want to use type="number"? It would do the conversion for you automatically.

Comment: cause i've others plugin working only with type="text"

Comment: That seems unlikely but sure.

Comment: Yes i know for replace function. But my goal is to run onchange function with replace inside, BEFORE all OTHERS onchange function i probably have to prevent errors.